# Is it possible to search for multiple categories in a single MapQuest API call?

Tags: url, query-string, mapquest

I am using the [MapQuest API](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/search-api/v2/radius-search/get/) to search for certain types of businesses within a 1 mile radius of a given location.

For example, to find grocery stores in downtown New York, I would use this link:

```
https://www.mapquestapi.com/search/v2/radius?origin=40.75,-73.98&radius=1&units=m&maxMatches=20&hostedData=mqap.ntpois|group_sic_code=?|541105&key=[API_KEY]
```

And to find restaurants, I would use this link:

```
https://www.mapquestapi.com/search/v2/radius?origin=40.75,-73.98&radius=1&units=m&maxMatches=20&hostedData=mqap.ntpois|group_sic_code=?|581208&key=[API_KEY]
```

You'll notice that both calls are the exact same except the [group_sic_code](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/search-api/v2/points-of-interest#sic-codes) was changed from "541105" (grocery stores) to "581208" (restaurants).

If possible, I would like to get the results from both queries in a single call.

After better understanding the syntax, it looks like it's a simple SQL query, so I thought I could just change it from a simple EQUALS statement to an IN statement like this:

```
hostedData=mqap.ntpois|group_sic_code IN (?)|541105,581208
```

But I get the following error:

```
Invalid number of parameters, expected 1, got 2
```

Is my request even possible?  Or do I have to make 1 call for each category?  I have over 50 categories I'd like to query, so I'd like to consolidate if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe try `IN (?,?)`? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That's a good thought, but it yields the same error unfortunately. Thanks though.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show exactly what you tried?

Comment: It might take issue with the comma in your `extraCriteria`. Alternately, try `group_sic_code=%3F%20OR%20group_sic_code=%3F|541105,581208` (that's `group_sic_code = ? OR group_sic_code = ?`, just URL encoded)

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!  I've updated my post to include the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `extraCriteria` is supposedly evaluated as SQL, you could try something like the following

```
hostedData%3Dmqap.ntpois%7Cgroup_sic_code%20IN(%3F%2C%3F)%7C541105%2C581208
```

(decoded)

```
hostedData=mqap.ntpois|group_sic_code IN(?,?)|541105,581208
```

However there appears to be a lot of string-splitting going on and it may not like the comma in `(?,?)`.

As an alternative, try a simple `OR` statement

```
hostedData%3Dmqap.ntpois%7Cgroup_sic_code%3D%3F%20OR%20group_sic_code%3D%3F%7C541105%2C581208
```

(decoded)

```
hostedData=mqap.ntpois|group_sic_code=? OR group_sic_code=?|541105,581208
```

Comment: The "OR" statement solution worked perfectly, thanks Phil!